# GitHub Issue API only return 30 results

Tags: javascript, html

```
function loadComments(auth) {
    fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/{myusername}/{myreponame}/issues", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Authorization: "token " + auth,
            },
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
}
```

when I try to run it, it only returns 30. I guess GitHub return results in portions when it is over 30. Any idea how I can get the rest of the results?

Comment: Why guess *I guess GitHub return results in portions*? What does their documentation say?

Comment: documentation says default portion is 30 items, you can add page parameter to your query to get more info or use per_page parameter to increase size of portion up to 100 results.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues#list-issues-assigned-to-the-authenticated-user

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the docs. It seems 30 results is the default results per page. You can set max to 100 results per page. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/issues.

*Note obviously this API works with a pagination system.*

Comment: can you make a full url?

Answer (score 0):

30 Results are the default results per page. This is based on the Rate Limit API. To view you're authenticated limit you can request this :

```
const octokit = new Octokit({
  auth: 'personal-access-token'
})

await octokit.request('GET /rate_limit', {})
```

or you can read more about the rate limit api at : [GitHub Rate Limit API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/rate-limit)